# Is the electrical conductivity only measurable in aqueous solutions?

Tags: aqueous-solution, intermolecular-forces, conductivity

I have been looking for other ways to measure it, but all I've found is through aqueous solutions. So I want to know if there's another way to do it, or why it isn't possible through other means.

Comment: Ultra pure water has very low conductivity, it is the dissolved ions that causes most of the conductivity. A high dielectric solvent is necessary to solvate ions thus any other high dielectric solvent can, in principle, also be used, eg. acetonitrile, n-methyl-formamide.

Comment: One can measure conductivity of everything that... conducts. If physical property and you seem to check too much about general chemistry instead.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into ionic liquids? Also in ionic complexes like poly (ethylene oxide)? For instance, look into these references:

1. P. V. Wright, Electrical conductivity in ionic complexes of poly(ethylene oxide), *Polymer International*, **1975**, *7(5)*, 319-327 (https://doi.org/10.1002/pi.4980070505).
2. Q.-G. Zhang, S.-S. Sun, S. Pitula, Q.-S. Liu, U. Welz-Biermann, J.-J. Zhang, Electrical conductivity of solutions of ionic liquids with methanol, ethanol, acetonitrile, and propylene carbonate, *J. Chem. Eng. Data*, **2011**, *56(12)*, 4659–4664 (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/je200616t).